# firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged triggered also on token refresh

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have migrated recently to firebase JS SDK v9 (in compat mode) and the first time the user auth token is refreshed the `auth.onAuthStateChanged` listener is called.

Is anybody experienced the same issue?

Docs are clear `After 4.0.0, the observer is only triggered on sign-in or sign-out.`

The next code reproduces the issue:

```
<html>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    const config = {
      apiKey: '',
      authDomain: '',
      databaseURL: '',
      projectId: '',
      storageBucket: '',
      messagingSenderId: '',
      appId: '',
    };
    const email = "mail12345@mail.com";
    const pass = "123456abc";
    const app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
    const auth = app.auth();

    const example = async () => {
      auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
        console.log('onAuthStateChanged user uid', user ? user.uid : 'null');

        if (!user) {
          try {
            await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
          } catch (e) {
            console.log('user already created');
          }

          console.log('signin')
          await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
        }
      })

      setInterval(() => {
        console.log('force token renewal');
        auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true);
      }, 5000)
    };

    example();
  </script>
</html>
```

If you run for the first time or if there is no session you get the output:

```
onAuthStateChanged user uid null   <-- becuase there is no session stored
user already created
signin
onAuthStateChanged user uid mqLHdtQhwJPaXqIEbDqFBwFoxLz1 <-- this is because the signin
force token renewal <-- run each 5 secs
```

Having a session stored if you refresh the page you find the next output:

```
onAuthStateChanged user uid mqLHdtQhwJPaXqIEbDqFBwFoxLz1 <-- recover the session
force token renewal
onAuthStateChanged user uid mqLHdtQhwJPaXqIEbDqFBwFoxLz1 <-- run again after refresh token
force token renewal <-- subsequent refresh token doesn not cause a call to onAuthStateChange
```

The problem is with the first refresh of token. After debugging a bit in chrome I found that on the first token refresh the funcion `notifyAuthListeners()`  from the file `auth_impl.ts` is invoked but the variable `this.lastNotifiedUid` is `undefined` which causes the refresh to be notified also to `onAuthStateChange` listeners.

[image]

Comment: That seems unexpected indeed. Can you edit your question to show a [minimal reproduction of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Update the original question with a reproducible example and outputs. Thanks

Comment: Nice catch. It sounds like a bug in the SDK as `lastNotifiedUid` probably should be set the first time the callback is called. I can't immediately find the code you shared in the SDK, but if you can: it might be best to report it as a bug on the [SDK repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk), to get the right eyes on it quickly.

Comment: Done last night and fixed before next day. Awesome team! https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5685

Comment: Awesome! Can you post a self-answer below, so that we can bring closure to this post too (while still keeping it available for others to find)?

Answer (score 0):

Finally the issue was reported as a bug at firebase-js-sdk project (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5685) and fixed in record time.